# I'm getting NA's applying separate() function over column of characters in R

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I'm trying to split a column that are formatted very differently. For example:

```
pharma <- c("DOXORUBICINA CLORH. FAM 50MG POL O LIOF",
                   "DROSPIRENONA/ETINILESTR. 3/0,02MG CM REC",
                   "DROSPIRENONA/ETINILESTR. 3/0,03MG CM REC",
                   "ETRAVIRINA 100 MG CM",
                   "AGALSIDASA ALFA 1MG/ML X 3,5 ML FAM")
```

And i'm using `separate()` to do the split in two different columns (i need separate the product name (i.e. DOXORUBICINA CLORH. FAM) and the details (50MG POL O LIOF)). The code is:

```
separate(data.frame(A = pharma), col = "A" , into = c("x","y"),sep = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\s*(?=[0-9])")
```

But i have the next by from R:

```
                                         x               y
1                  DOXORUBICINA CLORH. FAM 50MG POL O LIOF
2 DROSPIRENONA/ETINILESTR. 3/0,02MG CM REC            <NA>
3 DROSPIRENONA/ETINILESTR. 3/0,03MG CM REC            <NA>
4                               ETRAVIRINA       100 MG CM
5                          AGALSIDASA ALFA        1MG/ML X
Warning messages:
1: Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 1 rows [5]. 
2: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 2 rows [2, 3].
```

I can't see what is happening.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `sep = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\W+(?=[0-9])"` or `sep = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\W*(?=[0-9])"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data on the second and third row contains a dot between the letters and whitespace, your pattern only accounts for 0+ whitespace chars between a letter and a digit.

You may use

```
sep = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\W+(?=[0-9])"
```

or

```
sep = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\W*(?=[0-9])"
```

The `\W` pattern matches any non-word chars, any char other than letter, digit and `_`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9VKjFD/1).

R test:

```
> separate(data.frame(A = pharma), col = "A" , into = c("x","y"), sep = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\W*(?=[0-9])")
                        x               y
1 DOXORUBICINA CLORH. FAM 50MG POL O LIOF
2 DROSPIRENONA/ETINILESTR 3/0,02MG CM REC
3 DROSPIRENONA/ETINILESTR 3/0,03MG CM REC
4              ETRAVIRINA       100 MG CM
```

Comment: How can i do it with cases with strings like  "AGALSIDASA ALFA 1MG/ML X 3,5 ML FAM". separate() split it in 3 parts but i just need split on the first number. What can i do?

Comment: @DiegoGonzalezAvalos Then use `extract` with `"(.*?[a-zA-Z])\\W*([0-9].*)"` pattern: `df <- data.frame(A = pharma); df %>% extract(A, c("x", "y"), "(.*?[a-zA-Z])\\W*([0-9].*)")`

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(pharma, "(?<=[A-Za-z])\\s+(?=[0-9])", perl = TRUE))
```